# # of ways to place m books on n shelves

Tags: sorting, counting

This is a question about the the # of ways I can place the books on shelves.

I have to place a book on n number of shelves with m number of books; m >= n >= 1.

But I have to have atleast 1 book on each shelf.

I know with

(1*2*3(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)...(n+m-1)) / (1*2*3*...(n-2)(n-1))

=

(n+m-1)! / (n-1)!

it has every combination of ways to place the books on the shelves, but it also has the possibility of leaving a shelf empty, which does not satisfy having atleast 1 book on each shelf.

So I am wondering, what do I have to do to have the correct equation that satisfies having 1 book on each shelf.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to think. it's fun, and it's what homework is for. come back to us when you've *thought* of something that isn't working, and we'll help you figure out why that is.

Comment: This site is for programming questions.  http://math.stackexchange.com/ would be better for this question.